# Why is this isomorphism $M \otimes_K L \stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow} M^{[L:K]}$ an isomorphism of $M$ - algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, tensor-products

Suppose that $L/K$ is a finite separable extension of fields and let $M$ denote the Galois closure of $L$. Let $\textrm{Hom}_K(L,M)$ denote the set of all $K$ - algebra homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$. Since $L/K$ is separable we know that the number of elements in $\textrm{Hom}_K(L,M)$ is equal to $[L:K]$. Now I want to prove that we have an isomorphism of $M$ - algebras

$$\varphi : M \otimes_K L \stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow} M^{[L:K]}$$

**Proof that they are isomorphic as $K$ - modules :** Write $L = K(a)$ for some $ a\in L$ (we can do this via the primitive element theorem). Then

$$\begin{eqnarray*} M \otimes_K L &=& M \otimes_K K[a] \\
&\cong& M\otimes_K K[x]/(f) \hspace{3mm} \text{where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$} \\
&\cong& M[x]/(f)\\
&\cong& M[x]/(f_1\ldots f_{[L:K]}) \hspace{3mm} \text{where the $f_i$ are the distinct}\\ && \hspace{1.5in} \text{irreducible factors of $f$ since $M/L$ is Galois} \\
&\cong& M^{[L:K]}\end{eqnarray*}$$

where  the last step was using the Chinese remainder theorem. For the third last step, we consider the ses

$$ 0 \to (f) \to K[x] \to K[x]/(f) \to 0$$

and tensor with the exact functor $-\otimes_K M$ to get
$$0 \to (f) \otimes_K M \to K[x] \otimes_K M \to K[x]/(f) \otimes_K M \to 0$$

and so $$\begin{eqnarray*} M \otimes_K K[x]/(f) &\cong& K[x]/(f) \otimes_{K} M \\
&\cong& \frac{K[x] \otimes_{K} M}{f \otimes_K M}\\
& \cong& M[x]/(f) \end{eqnarray*}$$ where $(f)$ is now viewed as an ideal of $M[x]$.

> > **My question is:** The tensor product $M \otimes_K L$ is a left $M$ - module, but why is it also an $M$ - algebra? Also why are the isomorphisms above isomorphisms of $M$ - algebras and not just $K$ - modules?

Comment: My question is: What motivates your question? The primitive element theorem is a basic tool in field theory. And your proof is standard.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry I just realised I can do it without the primitive element theorem by inducting on the number of elements that we adjoint to $K$ to obtain $L$. I have changed my question now. I am sorry.

Comment: Don't you naturally get an $L$-algebra structure on the tensor product of two $L$-algebras? The algebra being commutative, $M$ will inject into its center, so you get an $M$-algebra structure, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're saying that $M \otimes_K L$ is a $K$ - algebra (I get that) and hence an $M$ - algebra (which I don't get)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how to use chinese remainder theorem  in above proo given by user about modules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $S=Hom_{K-alg}(L,M)$ be the set of $K$-algebra morphisms  $L\to M$ and consider the morphism of $K$-algebras $$f:L\to M^S:l\mapsto (s(l))_{s \in S}$$Since $M^S$ is an $M$-algebra, by the  universal property of extension of scalars for algebras,  $f$ extends to a morphism of $M$-algebras $$F:B=M\otimes_K L\to M^S:b=m\otimes l\mapsto (\sigma_s(b))_{s\in S}=(m\cdot s (l))_{s\in S}$$  Notice that the scalar multiplication by elements of $M$ on $M\otimes_K L$ occurs *via* the left factor.
Notice also that we have used the canonical identification $$Hom_{K-alg}(L,M)\stackrel {=}{\to} Hom_{L-alg}(M\otimes_KL,M):s\stackrel  {=}{\mapsto} [\sigma_s: m\otimes l \mapsto ms(l)]$$  The morphism $F$ is surjective by the **Reminder** below.
On the other hand the domain $B=M\otimes_K L$ of the morphism $F$ has dimension  $\operatorname {dim}_M M\otimes_K L=[L:K]$ while its codomain $M^S$ has dimension $[M^S:M]=\text {card}S=[L:K]$ too, because the extension  $L/K$ is separable.
So $F$ is a surjective linear map between vector spaces of same $M$-dimension and  is thus an isomorphism.
*Conclusion*
The morphism $$F:M\otimes_K L\to M^S:m\otimes l\mapsto (m\cdot \sigma (l))_{\sigma \in S}$$ is an isomorphism of $M$-algebras.
 Since $M^S\cong M^{[L:K]}$ your question is answered, but in a more canonical way.

**Reminder**
Let $M$ be a field, $B$ an $M$-algebra and $\sigma_1,\cdots, \sigma_n$ a finite family of distinct $M$-algebra morphisms $\chi_j:B\to M$.
Then the resulting algebra morphism $F:B\to M^n:b\mapsto (\sigma_1(b),\cdots, \sigma_n(b))$ is surjective.
This results from the Chinese Theorem since the maximal ideals $\operatorname {Ker}\sigma_j \subset B$ are pairwise comaximal.

Comment: I always love it when you answer my questions because man that answer above was slick! I should have noticed that $M \otimes_K L$ was just a way of "changing our coefficients". However, that being said in my proof above is there a way to see why my sequence of isomorphisms are isomorphisms of $M$ - algebras?

Comment: Dear BenjaLim, thanks for the kind words. My proof is, despite appearances, quite close to yours: the various $K$-homomorphisms $\sigma_i: L=K[a]\to M$ are obtained by sending $a$ to the various roots $a_i$ of the separable polynomial $f$ [in your notation $f_i=x-a_i$], so I think that you could prove that your isomorphism is one of $M$-algebras by following what happens to a decomposable tensor $m\otimes l \in M\otimes L$ along your displayed isomorphisms.

Comment: I like your proof in that it does not use the primitive element theorem. My proof will still work by induction (since any finite extension $L/K$ is always of the form $L = K(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ for $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in L$) but of course an element-free approach is always nicest. I will get back to you if I have any problems with my isomorphisms above.

Comment: I see the edit that you made above about Dedekind's theorem. Is this the same one on linear independence of characters as in page 51 of [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT400.pdf)? Thanks.

Comment: Dear BenjaLim, Milne's independence of characters is a corollary of the more general version  I quote, obtained by  taking  $L=K$,  $A=K[G]$ (the group algebra) and using the adjunction formula $Hom_{grp}(G,K^*)=Hom_{K-alg}(K[G],K)$.

Comment: sorry in which way the theorem of $M$-linear independence of the $K$-homomorphisms $L\mapsto M$ implies the subjectivity of the map? I can't see that honestly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually your comment does not say why the image has dimension $[L:K]$, which was my real question. Is my question clear now?

Comment: Yes I understood that. But that argument is about the dimension of the codomain, not the dimension of the image, which was my question. The image could be smaller than $M^S$, but in your proof you say that the image is exactly $M^S$ by the theorem of $M$-linear independence of the morphisms. I don't understand this.

Comment: Dear @Blacksmith: I have modified my answer and made more explicit the reason for surjectivity in a new section called  **Reminder**.