# Is there any mathematical operator that takes 3 or more operands?

Tags: operator-theory

All the common arithmetic operators operate on two operands. For example, <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.

I am interested to know if there is any mathematical operator that works upon 3 or more operands.

Comment: Wouldn't integration be 4 operands? (upper bound, lower bound, the function being integrated, and the variable being integrated with respect to)

Comment: I mean, Riemann integration for continuous functions can be defined as a limiting process of the function at specific inputs, addition, and multiplication. Does a limiting process imply it isn't the composition of multiple two input operands?

Comment: Whether or not one (or all) functions of three arguments can be written as a composition of functions of two arguments is a separate issue. It is also the gravamen of Hilbert's Thirteenth Problem, and makes for a fascinating rabbit-hole to fall down on a cold afternoon stuck indoors.

Comment: Specifically, google resolvent bounds (warning: high level topic). See here https://cpb-us-e2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uci.edu/dist/5/2709/files/2019/05/Advancement-to-Candidacy-Topic-Proposal.pdf

Answer (score 2):

$V\otimes_{K} W - $[Tensor product over a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756387/tensor-product-over-a-ring)?

Although it's worth noting that usually the things on either side of the operator symbol are of more-or-less the same type, and that's the case with $V$ and $W$ here, while $K$ is of a different "type", so some might argue that it's not a full-on "operand" like $V$ and $W$ are.

It's all kind of pedantic, though, as it's all just functions, just with different number of arguments:

- Negative, aka "unary negative", written "$-x$", is a function of one variable, say "$N(x)$".
- Difference, aka "subtraction", written "$a-b$", is a function of two variables, say "$D(a,b)$".
- Tensor product over a ring, written as above, is a function of three variables, say "$T(V,W,K)$".

[Note: Saying "they're all functions" is a bit off, as the formal definition of a function requires a proper set as a domain, and that tensor product probably belongs in a proper (large) category, but I don't think that's the level you're asking at.]