# A question about étale algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $A$ be any finite étale $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (i.e. it's isomorphic to a finite direct product of number fields).

Let $S$ be the set of all $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphisms $A \to \bar{\mathbb{Q}}.$

I'm trying to show that the natural map
$$\Phi:A\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\longrightarrow \text{Hom}_{\,\text{Set}}(S,\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$$
given by
$$\Phi:a\otimes x \longmapsto \big(s \mapsto s(a)x\big)$$
is an isomorphism of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-vector spaces.

---

I have been able to show that $S$ is a finite set of size $\dim_\mathbb{Q}A.$

Hence $\dim_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}(A\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\bar{\mathbb{Q}})=\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(\text{Hom}_{\,\text{Set}}(S,\bar{\mathbb{Q}})).$

It therefore suffices to either that $\Phi$ is injective or $\Phi$ is surjective.

I feel that surjectivity will be easier to show but I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly conjectured, it suffices to prove that the map $\Phi$ is surjective.
If it were not the case, then there would exist a hyperplane
 $H\subset Map(S,\overline {\mathbb Q})$ containing the image of $\Phi$ .
That hyperplane would be defined by a family $\lambda =(\lambda_s)$  of numbers $\lambda_s\in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and would be of the form $$H_\lambda =\{\alpha:S\to \bar Q\vert \sum_{s\in S} \lambda_s\alpha(s)=0\} $$
Since  $\Phi(A)\subset \operatorname {Im}(\Phi)=\Phi(A\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\bar{\mathbb{Q}})\subset H_\lambda$ 
the equality $\sum_{s\in S}\lambda_s s(a)=0$  would obtain for all $a\in A$.
But that would contradict  Dedekind's theorem on independence of homomorphisms, namely [Bourbaki, Algebra II, Chapter v, Theorem 1, page 27](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GXT1CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Dedekind+theorem+of+independence+of+homomorphisms&source=bl&ots=BSkgtN3FHn&sig=dYv1EbPkW4VB2yr-C1d0-oantow&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn4NSfyfnaAhXrDcAKHZfBD04Q6AEwDHoFCAAQiAE#v=onepage&q=Dedekind%20theorem%20of%20independence%20of%20homomorphisms&f=false).
.

Comment: **A riddle:** Dedekind's theorem is valid for any  commutative algebra over a field $k$ and any field extension $k\subset L$, and has nothing to do with the "étale" concept. So where, dear user,  have I used   the étale hypothesis, without which the result mentioned  in the question is false?

Comment: Dear Georges, thank you for your super answer (I cherish many of your answers on this site!). I think that the étale hypothesis is needed for S to have size equal to [A:Q] but nowhere else - is that right?

Comment: Also, if I might pester you some more in a related direction, in your "reminder" in your answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263192/ I understand why the kernels are maximal ideals (they are kernels of surjective homomorphisms onto fields) but I don't see why they are distinct (and hence comaximal) - would you mind explaining?

Comment: Actually I think I've worked it out. If $\sigma,\tau:B\to M$ are $M$-algebra homs with $\ker\sigma=\ker\tau,$ then for any $b \in B$ one has $\sigma(\sigma(b)\cdot 1-b)=\sigma(b)-\sigma(b)=0$ and so $\sigma(b)\cdot 1 - b \in \ker\sigma=\ker\tau$ and hence $0=\tau(\sigma(b)\cdot 1 - b)=\sigma(b)-\tau(b).$ We have thus proved that $\sigma = \tau.$

Comment: Dear user 350031:  yes, $\operatorname {card} S=[A:\mathbb Q]$ is exactly where we use étale. Bravo!